# Abyss web server and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abyss

I have got [Abyss](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws) web server on my [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7) 64 bit computer. I followed the instructions regarded in [this official link](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/python.html) to add [python](/questions/tagged/python) support to the server, regarding that I did not downloaded the Active Python considered in the documentation, I just used a previously installed Python 3.3 on my machine.

I have wrote very simple python script:

```
print("Hello")
```

Then I saved it as `test.py` in the server's htdocs, then I tried to access `http://localhost:9090/test.py` but the server returns **Error 500** Internal Server Error the log line that record this error is:

> **cgi.log:**
>
> [21/Dec/2014:01:33:54 +0200]  CGI: [C:\Python33\python.exe
> test.py ] URI: /test.py   Bad CGI header line [Hello]
>
> **access.log:**
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2014:01:33:54 +0200] "GET /test.py HTTP/1.1" 500 412 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

So how could I fix the CGI header line?

Comment: This might help, [How to use Python in the web](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/webservers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to fix the CGI header, thanks to [Himal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189040/himal), the idea is printing out content type followed by a blank line, then the script works fine:

```
print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print ()
print("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")
```